# Using wp_enqueue_script in a wordpress plugin

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

This is my current code:

```
<script src="http://unibet-affiliate.enetscores.com/xjs/hour/theme/affiliate/361/client"></script>
<script>
__initLivescore({"c1":"F0F0F0","c2":"BABCC3","c4":"FFFFFF","c5":"FFFFFF","c6":"C90000","affiliate_id":"0","menu":"1","sportFK":"1","odds":"decimal","lang":"3","timezone":"AUTO","selected_tab":"all"});
</script>
```

It is possible to use wp_enqueue_script for this code?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

put these

```
__initLivescore({"c1":"F0F0F0","c2":"BABCC3","c4":"FFFFFF","c5":"FFFFFF","c6":"C90000","affiliate_id":"0","menu":"1","sportFK":"1","odds":"decimal","lang":"3","timezone":"AUTO","selected_tab":"all"});
```

code in a js like demo.js file. 
and then use wp_enqueue_scripts and enqueue this file

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name1', 'http://unibet-affiliate.enetscores.com/xjs/hour/theme/affiliate/361/client');
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name2',  plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/demo.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```